# Web API Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is Windows Azure the only hosting option we have (other than "Selfhost") for the Web API? If not, where are the hosts that support Web API? Many Google searches only returned options for Self-hosting.

Answer (score 7):

Look at http://www.asp.net/hosting for an official list of partners. WebAPI can be hosted as part of ASP.NET it just requires .NET 4.0+.

Also look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api for how to deploy a WebAPI to IIS.

Comment: Oh, so I can just host my new Web API site with my current Host, since they support 4.0+? (looking at link now) - Thanks @Romoku

Comment: @jAsOn Yeah WebAPI comes as part of the ASP.NET MVC 4, but there is a nuget package that allows one to host WebAPI without MVC4 being installed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this:

[Free hosting at Somee.com](https://somee.com/freeaspnethosting.aspx)

Pros:
It supports MVC, Ajax and few other techs.

Cons:
Server sometime go down without notice for short-time.

Hope this helps.